# Good idea to use @mixin for "DRY'ing" up @keyframes?

Tags: sass

Is it a good idea to use mixins to DRY up keyframes as the following example:

Note that I just have left and right here but if I where to have more I think the use of @mixins is a better choice. I am not familiar with the customs of writing neat scss/sass, what is the preferred way?

```
    @keyframes fade-in-left {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        }

        100% {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
    @keyframes fade-in-right {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
        }

        100% {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
```

vs

```
@mixin fade-in-horizontally($direction_value) {
    @keyframes fade-in-left {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translate3d($direction_value, 0, 0);
        }

        100% {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixins are great but should not be used just to shorten some code. In that case, you only want to define your `@keyframes` once.

So, here is a third option: using a [list](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#lists) and an [each directive](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#each-directive).

```scss
$keyframes-fade: (
  ('left', -100%),
  ('right', 100%)
);

@each $dir, $translateTX in $keyframes-fade {
  @keyframes fade-in-#{$dir} {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate3d($translateTX, 0, 0);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
  }
}
```

This will make your code shorter while keeping it easy to understand.

[You can see the output here](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/8c7508ed15385c13ebcba3f45985664f)

Comment: Wow, amazing! I didn't eve know about that @each thingy. This is even better!